# Live Stream APIs/Solutions

Tags: api, live-streaming, twitch

Twitch has this feature on their video player where you can create short clips of someone's stream. Does anyone know if there are any Live Streaming APIs that have this functionality? I want to build a twitch clone of some sort with the ability to clip mid-stream.

Answer (score 0):

You should try looking onto the **FFmpeg** Library.

FFmpeg is a popular open-source software library that allows users to encode, decode, record, convert and stream audio and video. It has also the ability to edit video.

It is a Command line CLI library, but there is as well an API to control the library from a node.js environment  **fluent-ffmpeg**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg